# How to create character identity with mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a code have format: Mxxxxxx (x is number) and Mxxxxxx is unique in mysql database. How can i do that? I'm trying to use identity (AUTO_INCREMENT)!

Comment: Is the first letter the same for every code?

Comment: storing xxxx as a number makes a lot more sense. why you want to do this?

Comment: You can't auto-increment a string - just give your id the `xxxxx` part and if the M is a constant character you just prepend it outside the scope of the database or in your `select` query. e.g. `select concat( 'M', id) from myTable where ...`